# Category theory problem? Linear Algebra problem? Pull-back transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm having a hard time solving this. I'm taking a proof-based undergraduate linear algebra course that has no assigned textbook and this has been making things a little hard since the only resource I have are my notes from lecture -- he's doing things his own way (starts with set theory, then group theory, et cetera). I don't seem to be able to find anything that gives some insight to this problem.

Could someone give me a hint on how to solve this problem or point me to some material online that could help? Maybe notes in PDF or something? Oh also, what *exactly* is meant by "Pullback" Thank you. [image]

$\mathbb{R}(X)$, $\mathbb{R}(Y)$ is the set of functions that are mapped to $\mathbb{R}$. For example,       $\mathbb{R}(X)=\{ f : X\to\mathbb{R} \}$ and $\mathbb{R}(Y)=\{ g : Y\to\mathbb R \}$ where $\mathbb R$ are the real numbers.

Edit: I have figured out that given a $g$ in $Y$, $f = g \cdot \varphi = \varphi^*(g)$, but I don't see how a,b and thus c are true.

Comment: Let $T \in \mathbb{R}(Y)$.  Then $(\varphi^*(T))(x) = T(\varphi(x))$ for $x\in X$.

Comment: This problem seems interesting, would you clarify what is $\mathbb{R}(X)$ where $X$ is a set?

Comment: Just did. You may edit, I haven't learned LaTex yet, but will soon!

Comment: @AlessioRanallo

Comment: @AlvinJin, I was able to figure that out, but I don't know what to do with that information.

Comment: @physicsmajor Applying definitions is a good way to go now :)

Answer (score 0):

The strategy of proof is very similar for all of the three points: I'll write down (a), and if you want I can write more also regarding (b) and (c).

So, for (a): say that $\varphi$ is surjective. Then we want to show that $\varphi^*$ is injective, i.e. $\varphi^*(f)$ equals the zero map only if $f$ already was the zero map.
Indeed, suppose $\varphi^*(f)(x)=f\cdot\varphi=0\ \forall x$. Then it must be $f(x)=0\ \forall x$ in the image of $\varphi$. But this image is the whole space! Then $f$ must have been the zero map already - you don't lose any domain by precomposing.

On the other hand, suppose your $\varphi^*$ is injective: then $\varphi^*(f)(x)=f\cdot\varphi=0\ \forall x$ implies $f=0$. But now you could for example argue ad absurdum - pick a point which is not in the image of $\varphi$ and a function which is not zero only in that point - then $\varphi^*(f)=0$, but $f$ was not. Then surjectivity must hold, and the two conditions are equivalent.

You should approach (b) and (c) with the same spirit. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I'll work through your advice to convince myself then approach b and c, thank you, @nelv

Comment: yes! unlucky notation choice, sry

Comment: It's alright, thank you!

Comment: I tried to edit the parts I told you about, switched the $f$'s for the $g$'s and changed the members of the sets, please check to see if I maybe the correct changes when you can, thank you. @nelv

Comment: I think the edit was rejected, but it was definitively ok :-) that's what I meant

Comment: what did you mean by: "then $\varphi^*(g)=0$, but $g$ was not." I'm not sure what you meant exactly. I know you're proving by contradiction and you're saying that we pick a point, say $c \notin Y$ and a function that is not zero only at that point i.e. $h \in \mathbb{R}(Y)$ such that $h(c) \neq 0$ and $h = 0$ everywhere else

Comment: so, you consider g \cdot varphi. Since g cannot reach the only point where it is not zero (this point is not in the image of varphi), it is the zero function (pictures may help?): but the original g was chosen in such a way that it is not the zero fct, hence a contradiction! (feel free to ask further, I'm here :-))